# Get all Checked Paper-checkbox in Polymer 2.0

Tags: checkbox, polymer-2.x

I want to disable/enable a submit button based on the state of `paper-checkboxe`s in my `iron-form`. So, for that I am using the `iron-change` event.

In that event, I want to see whether any checkbox is checked or not. One approach is to loop over all checkboxes.

Is there any other way in Polymer to get the length of checked paper-checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The `paper-checkbox` has 'checked' attribute set.So, we can do something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('paper-checkbox[checked]')
```